# lubuntu Live DVD unable to boot stuck at loading screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, lubuntu, system

i downloaded the lubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso and  then used  rufus to make it bootaable from usb 
. Now I am booting  but the boot is stuck on the loading screen (this one: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-tD-yi63zyj8/UAEATpqyfSI/AAAAAAAAWKA/12PoRg9MHwk/s320/How-to-Customize-Ubuntu-Splash-and-Login-Screen.jpg) for more than an hour now.

any help

btw  this  only haappens in ubuntu/lubuntu  i waas using puppylinux without issues

when i  use  the  remove the "quiet splash option get  stuck 
aat

started update UTMP About System Runlevel changes

Comment: Did you remember to [verify the download](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu) before creating the LiveUSB?

Comment: yes  i  have  booted  the  stick on others  pc  with no issues

Comment: Unless the *others pc* had identical hardware (thus same packages were used for hardware) your using it on another box may not prove your write to media was perfect, thus I'd suggest using the *Check disk for defects" option mentioned on https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html  (also covered in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where CD refers to any install media, ie. cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash-card/..)  Any other possibilities would be pure guess as you've provided no details (kernel used on working system was?)